# how can I create on my own a auto-self created datetime column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, printing, dataset

i have a datetime dataframe
assume it is the following

```
    Datetime
0   2022-09-06 12:33:40
1   2022-09-06 12:33:50
2   2022-09-06 12:34:00
3   2022-09-06 12:34:10
4   2022-09-06 12:34:20
```

2022 - 09 - 06 (09-06 is 9th june)

```
Datetime
```

40490   2022-06-14 05:02:00
40491   2022-06-14 05:02:10
40492   2022-06-14 05:02:20
40493   2022-06-14 05:02:30
.
.
Datetime
301492  2022-02-10 10:05:40
301493  2022-02-10 10:05:50
301494  2022-02-10 10:06:00
301495  2022-02-10 10:06:10
301496  2022-02-10 10:06:20

this DateTime dataframe contains 1.000.000 rows until the 2022-5-10 ( 5th octomber) with the step of 10 seconds
the problem is that many dates follow the formation year-month-day and other dates in the dataframe follow the formation od year - day - month

how couldd the datetime changes on its own ?
what I mean is that I have an initial datetime  2022-09-06 12:33:40 and I want to make a code that after a x number of seconds will change the day and after of y number of seconds will change the month creating a new column that follows this pattern
2022-month-day hour-minutes-seconds
does anybody know how can I fix my problem?

Comment: So, do you want entire column in the dataframe to follow the same pattern (YY-MM-DD)? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: yes ( i edited my question as it needed it )

Comment: Can you elaborate with examples?

Comment: Still not clear. You want to keep switching the format of date after X seconds? You need to post a final DF the way you see it; otherwise, there would be a lot of back and forth as your post is not clear

Comment: due to the fact that other dates follow the first formation and other follow the other i want a way to make all the dates following the same formation for example

Comment: 2022-day month hours-minutes-seconds

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: because otherwise i cant merge with an other datetime dataframe